# What should I use for implementing list feature in GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt

I want to implement list like "stackoverflow question list" (where each row has multiple items, text, tags, user, time etc) in GWT. What should be most appropriate approach?

I tried using FlowPanel and inside that "HTML elements" so result will be DIVs inside DIV.
But, then CSS is pain.. (unable to set right aligned multiple rows and left aligned user profile image etc)

If I use table then, it GWT does not support row rendering. Need to work on cell, it is again pain.

so, Any suggestions? 
(Please exclude GXT or SmartGWT like other heavy weight frameworks, just want to use core GWT. )

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major answer here is 'it depends'.

The general way I try to approach anything with GWT is to come up with an HTML mockup. Once you have a static version of the layout you want, complete with CSS, it's actually quite straightforward to convert this into GWT code. See this article on '[tags first gwt](http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/tags-first-gwt/)' for well written example.

The point to keep in mind with GWT is that ultimately, the browser is going to have to deal with a DOM structure you build up, so if you can make it correct without GWT, it is far easier to then make it correct with GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Use DockPanel for contents like multiple items, text, tags, user, time etc...Then add the dockpanel to FlexTable.FlexTable will support to add rows.

Answer (score 0):

How About gwt Grid? even that supports text and table.

Comment: GWT Grid? core GWT Grid? Does it support table span? I don't think so.